# SKSpriteNode are not falling in root scene

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am adding few nodes with a repeated time interval but they all are not falling naturally .I have added also

> `item!.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true`
>
> `item!.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true`

and i am calling

> `self.scene?.addChild(itemController.spawnItem())` from Gameplayscene

```
func spawnItem()-> SKSpriteNode{
        let item : SKSpriteNode?;
        if Int(randomBetweenNumbers(firstnum: 0, secondnum: 10)) >= 6{
            item = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bomb");
            item!.name = "Bomb";
            item!.setScale(0.6);
            item!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: item!.size.height / 2);
        }
        else{
            let num = Int(randomBetweenNumbers(firstnum: 1, secondnum: 6));
            item = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Fruit\(num)");
            item!.name = "Fruit";
            item!.setScale(0.7);
            item!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: item!.size.height / 2);
        
        }
        
        item!.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.FRUIT_AND_BOMB
       
        item!.zPosition = 3;
        item!.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        item!.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        item!.physicsBody?.isResting = false
        item!.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        item!.position.x = randomBetweenNumbers(firstnum: minX, secondnum: maxX)
        item!.position.y = 400
        return item!;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what "not falling naturally" means?

Comment: My guess is, you haven't set up physics in your GameScene correctly.

Comment: Just taking a look at the code, you forgot one line that should make it work. Add `physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self` in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: i solved this issues by setting the my scene's gravity property.y  to -0.8 ,it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My scene's gravity property y parameter was set to 0 .so all nodes which are being added are not falling to bottom layer so changed  to -0.8 it worked for me

Comment: do not even set it,  the default is earth gravity